# product of one dimensional basis functions spanning two dimensional space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Lets assume I have a set of basis functions $h_1(x),h_2(x), ...$ spanning the whole hilbert space of one dimensional square integrable functions. Now I want a basis set that spans the the whole hilbert space of two dimensional square integrable functions $f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),...$. Is it correct that all possible combinations of products $h_m(x)h_n(y)$ form such a basis? How would one prove that? Thanks very much ...

Comment: I assume you're talking about an orthonormal basis $\{ h_{n} \}$ of $H$. Then it is easy to check that $k_{m,n}(x,y)=h_{m}(x)h_{n}(y)$ defines an orthonormal subset of the product $L^{2}$ space, and this orthonormal subset is complete if you can establish Parseval's equality for at least a dense subset of the product $L^{2}$ space. You'll probably want to use complete measures.

Comment: Start by showing that you can represent indicator functions of rectangles. (This is trivial because these are actually products of one dimensional square integrable functions.) Conclude from this and properties of the product measure that you can represent indicator functions of any finite measure set. Conclude that you can represent any simple function. Then do the usual thing.